# Positioning three list elements - 2 and 3 directly below 1

Tags: css, layout, positioning

I'd like to position these three list items so that they both float to the right of the page and item 1 sits directly above items 2 and 3.

This is the html bit:

```
<div class="header-text">
    <div class="header-contact">
         <ul class="header-contact-list">
                            <li><a href="">item 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">item 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">item 3</a></li>
         </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Currently, they all float to the right as I've added `float: right` to list elements (interestingly, item 1 is the farthest right, then item 2, then 3), however, they are still on the same line. What am I missing? I cannot cheat my way out of this with `padding-right` as I will need to change its colors as well.

Comment: Do you want item 1 on one row and the other two on the next row?

Comment: yes, exactly! Sorry I wasn't very clear

Comment: See my answer, if that'll help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question, but if you want to align the list to the right with item 1 on one row and item 2 and 3 on the next row, this is how you could do it.

Add `display: inline-block;` to items 2 and 3:

```
.header-contact-list li:not(:first-of-type) {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

and add `float: right;` to `.header-contact`

Comment: Thank you! I realize I wasn't being too clear but your solution worked. I didn't know you can include "not" in CSS selectors, so that's a bonus :) thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, it's a "good-to-know"-thing in CSS :)